# Weird mySQL behavior in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I'm having some serious trouble with a freshly installed copy of mySQL server under Ubuntu 10.10. I installed with apt and supplied a password at that time. Installation went fine, but the server is behaving very strangely.

First, to test the database, I created a php file with

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "myPassword") or die(mysql_error());
```

where myPassword is the one I entered when it asked, during installation. That gave me an access denied error. I tried to shell into the mySQL server to pursue a solution I read about. The normal syntax didn't work, and to get anything but "access denied", I had to do

```
mysql -u root password myPassword
```

However, instead of a mysql shell, it just spits out a list of parameters and variables. So at this point, I'm stumped; I haven't worked with mySQL through a command line in a couple of years, but none of this behavior is familiar, and I can't find a way to interact with the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The mysql command-line parameter for supplying a password is `-p`, not `password`.  You should also leave out spaces.  For example:

```
mysql -uroot -pmyPassword
```

If you don't want to risk your password being exposed...

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

...will prompt you for your password and hide the characters as you type them.

Comment: What I was pointing out as being weird is that using the -p parameter was resulting in an access denied error, regardless of whether I used '-uroot' or '-u root'. This is partly what I meant by "weird behavior".

Answer (score 0):

If you have apparmor installed (this is default) it can cause problems when you go outside the narrowly-defined defaults set up by ubuntu.

The things that mysql is allowed to touch is defined here: `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql`

If you've put your socket file elsewhere, you would get an access-denied message.

To look at things more closely, run your mysql client like so:

```
strace -e file mysql <blah blah>
```

This will print out any system-level file operations on stderr. You can then see exactly which operation is causing the permissions error. If you don't see an issue, you might use `-e network` instead, to see network operations.